# Mocha Async before() hook timing out

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, asynchronous, mocha.js

### Background

I am creating a dummy server using [`net`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) from Node.js in my Mocha test.

I have a dummy test, and I want to start the server before the test starts, and kill it after:

```
"use strict";

/*global describe, it, expect, before, after*/

const net = require("net");

describe("dummy server test", () => {

    const dummyReader = {
        IP: "localhost",
        port: 4002,
        server: undefined,
        socket: undefined
    };

    before("Starts dummy server", done => {

        dummyReader.server = net.createServer(socket => {
            dummyReader.socket = socket;
            done();
        });

        dummyReader.server.listen(dummyReader.IP, dummyReader.port);

    });

    after("Kills dummy server", done => {
        dummyReader.server.close();
        dummyReader.socket.destroy();
        done();
    });

    it("should pass", () => {
        expect(true).to.be.true;
    });
});
```

### Problem

The problem is that my async `before` hook never completes. For a reason I can't understand `done` is never called, and thus the hook times out.

I tried increasing the time out, believing it could fix the issue, but to no avail.

### Question

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You need to flip the host address and port arguments in `dummyReader.server.listen(...);`. The port comes first, and the host second.
2. The callback to `net.createServer` won't be called until something actually connects to the server, but you have nothing connecting to it.

With the following `before` hook the code will run. I've added code that creates a connection right away for illustration purposes.

```
before("Starts dummy server", done => {

    dummyReader.server = net.createServer(socket => {
        dummyReader.socket = socket;
        done();
    });

    dummyReader.server.listen(dummyReader.port,
                              dummyReader.IP,
                              undefined,
                              () => {
                                  // For illustration purposes,
                                  // create a connection as soon
                                  // as the server is listening.
                                  net.connect(
                                      dummyReader.port,
                                      dummyReader.IP);
                              });
});
```

Seems to me though that what you should be doing is ending the `before` hook as soon as the server is *listening* and then connect to it in your tests. Here's an illustration of how it can be done:

```
"use strict";

/*global describe, it, expect, before, after*/

const net = require("net");

describe("dummy server test", () => {

    const dummyReader = {
        IP: "localhost",
        port: 6002,
        server: undefined,
        socket: undefined
    };

    before("Starts dummy server", done => {
        dummyReader.server = net.createServer(socket => {
            console.log("got a new socket!");
            dummyReader.socket = socket;
        });

        dummyReader.server.listen(dummyReader.port,
                                  dummyReader.IP,
                                  undefined,
                                  () => {
                                      done();
                                  });
    });

    after("Kills dummy server", done => {
        dummyReader.server.close();
        // dummyReader.socket.destroy();
        done();
    });

    let prevSocket;
    it("should pass", (done) => {
        net.connect(dummyReader.port, dummyReader.IP, () => {
            console.log(dummyReader.socket.address());
            prevSocket = dummyReader.socket;
            done();
        });
    });

    it("should pass 2", (done) => {
        net.connect(dummyReader.port, dummyReader.IP, () => {
            console.log(dummyReader.socket.address());
            console.log("same socket?",
                        prevSocket === dummyReader.socket);
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Each time you connect, a new `net.Socket` object is created and assigned to `dummyReader.socket` and so you can access it from inside you test if needed. I've peppered the code with `console.log` statements to show some key values. When I run it here, I get:

```
  dummy server test
got a new socket!
{ address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 6002 }
    ✓ should pass
got a new socket!
{ address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 6002 }
same socket? false
    ✓ should pass 2


  2 passing (71ms)
```

Comment: Very complete post! Thanks! I will be sure to remember you next time I have a similar issue (which might be sooner than what you think :P )